Wordpress images linking to empty image folders after migration from free wordpress.com site
I've been trying to migrate a free wordpress.com site to a Siteground hosted site. After migrating, the images are all linking to unviewable image folders instead of the images in the media library. The files are there in the media library and the posts and pages are there though.
I migrated the site using **xml **files and the built in importer. The original wordpress.com site is still active, so it did in fact download the images and they are in the correct folders in the media library. On the original wordpress.com site, the images on posts and pages link like this:
https://mywebsite.com/2023/08/02/thisisthepostname/thisistheimagename/
Most of the images are in gallery blocks but not all of them. The featured images work correctly for some reason.
But now, when this format is used on SIteground, the thumbnails are broken and if I click on the gallery links I get:
"Oops! That page can't be found."
I have noticed that when I edit the resolution for the galleries, it fixes the issue, but this is a lot of work to do one by one

This could be a few things. 1. try to reset permissions on the images on the server. 2. Make sure the URL to the images in the gallery are correct. Are they still linking back to your old site? If so, replace the URLs in the database. 3. You could try adding a thumbnail regeneration plugin and running that. That may force database update for your images. This is a really hard question to answer without some sort of debugging code, or access to your site.
